# Column-wise average over unequal number of values in matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, average, indices

I am looking for an easy way to obtain the column-wise average of a subset of values in a matrix (indexed by a logical matrix), preferably without having to use a loop. The problem that I am experiencing is that because the number of values in each column is different, matlab collapses the values-matrix and its column-wise mean becomes the total mean (of the entire matrix). Is there a specific function or easy workaround for this problem? See below for an example.

```
    %% define value matrix and logical indexing matrix

    values=[1 2 3 4; 5 6 7 8; 9 10 11 12];
    indices=[1 0 0 1; 0 1 0 1; 1 1 0 0];
    indices=indices==1; %convert to logical

    %% calculate column-wise average

    mean(values(indices),1)
```

Comment: Why without loops? I'm sure that, for array sizes where the implementation matters (i.e. very large arrays that take a non-trivial time to process) the loop approach will be the fastest. Loops are no longer slow in MATLAB, and they haven't been in at least 15 years. It's about time people drop this "avoid loops at all cost" mentality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### `accumarray`-based approach

Use the column index as a grouping variable for [`accumarray`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

```
[~, col] = find(indices);
result = accumarray(col(:), values(indices), [size(values,2) 1], @mean, NaN).';
```

Note that:

- The second line uses `(:)` to force the first input to be a column vector. This is needed because the first line may produce `col` as a row or column vector, depending on the size of `indices`.
- `NaN` is used as fill value. This is specified as the fifth input to `accumarray`.
- The third input to `accumarray` defines output size. It is necessary to specify it explicitly (as opposed to letting `accumarray` figure it out) in case the last columns of `indices` only contain `false`.

#### Hacky approach

Multiply and divide element-wise by `indices`. That will turn unwanted entries into `NaN`, which can then be ignored by [`mean`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mean.html) using the `'omitnan'` option:

```
result = mean(values.*indices./indices, 1, 'omitnan');
```

#### Manual approach

Multiply element-wise by `indices`, sum each column, and divide element-wise by the sum of each column of `indices`:

```
result = sum(values.*indices, 1) ./ sum(indices, 1);
```